# airtable get request 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, get, fetch, http-status-code-401, airtable

I made a GET request to [airtable](https://airtable.com/) table, but with the right key and right url he give me the 401 (Unauthorized) error.

```
fetch("https://api.airtable.com/...")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: did this help ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an encoded URL for the request?
Check out this tool it will help set the URL correctly for `GET` request

[https://codepen.io/airtable/full/rLKkYB][1]

Also are you using the Airtable.js npm package?

Comment: initially i made with the GET request, but these request give me only the first line of records, so i  see the API documentation for list request and i put the right url with the right key, but the response is 401 (Unauthorized) every time. I'm not using airtable .js

Comment: Ok, can you post a little more of the code that you have?

Comment: function gg() {
            fetch("https://api.airtable.com/v0/appkpmjhrpinXDDSn/Table%201? 
            maxRecords=3&view=Grid%20view?api_key=key...")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error))
        }

Comment: Did this help you at all and slove the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`401` Unauthorized Accessing a protected resource without authorization or with invalid credentials.

You are not validating the API key which prevents you from getting the authorization

```
var Airtable = require('airtable');
Airtable.configure({
    endpointUrl: 'https://api.airtable.com',
    apiKey: 'keyxxxxx'
});
var base = Airtable.base('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm Airtable API Key and Airtable base key.

```
fetch("https://api.airtable.com/v0/appXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Resources?api_key=keyXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```